# Nexus 5 phone not detected when connected to Arduino board

Tags: android, arduino, usb, adk

Initially i connected my Arduino Mega ADK board and built the Example program demokit from ADK_release_20120606

As soon as i connect my Nexus 5 to the Arduino Mega ADK board it showed a pop up message to download the necessary app then i downloaded and installed the standard Android ADK demo kit( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.diyphonegadgets.DemoKit&hl=en )

But after downloading also i am unable to detect my phone which is connected to the Arduino. After verifying and building it in Arduino IDE my phone is just in charging mode So can anyone please tell me how to rectify it